# What does the circumflex accent do in an if condition?

Tags: javascript, python

I have Javascript code here that I have to turn into Python code but I don't really know where to start. The function in question is:

```
    function test(e, t, n, r) {
        console.log("INPUT = " + e, t, n, r);
        for (var i, o = 0; e < r; e++) {
            if (o > n.length - 1 && (o = 0), e < r) {
                if ((i = t[e] ^ n.charCodeAt(o)) === t[e]) {
                    console.debug("Error decoding sample preview", t[e], n[o], o, n.length, n.charCodeAt(o));
                    break
                }
                t[e] = i
            }
            o++
        }
        console.log("OUTPUT = " + e, t, n, r);
        return e
    }

-- CONSOLE LOG --
    INPUT = 0 
    Uint8Array(202710) [206, 159, 164, 117, 53, 55, 51, 165, 41, 229, 254, 16, 113, 47, 55, 181, 50, 67, 149, 232, 52, 122, 205, 82, 123, 46, 153, 176, 98, 65, 35, 67, 149, 42, 168, 50, 49, 118, 103, 161, 37, 35, 17, 189, 28, 104, 207, 169, 134, 45, 98, 52, 57, 183, 182, 227, 179, 177, 53, 55, 49, 54, 170, 183, 228, 187, 49, 60, 157, 132, 200, 192, 193, 148, 52, 49, 53, 51, 80, 216, 210, 71, 156, 203, 206, 193, 98, 52, 127, 223, 206, 155, 244, 49, 53, 38, 182, 176, 162, 196, …]
     1d415717-0c41-b480 50677

    OUTPUT = 50677 
    Uint8Array(202710) [255, 251, 144, 68, 0, 0, 2, 146, 4, 213, 157, 36, 64, 2, 85, 129, 10, 115, 164, 140, 0, 75, 248, 101, 74, 25, 180, 128, 1, 117, 18, 110, 247, 30, 144, 2, 0, 18, 83, 144, 16, 20, 32, 138, 49, 88, 172, 157, 183, 0, 0, 0, 1, 135, 135, 135, 135, 128, 0, 0, 0, 1, 135, 135, 135, 143, 0, 17, 255, 176, 240, 240, 240, 240, 0, 0, 0, 4, 97, 239, 255, 119, 255, 255, 255, 236, 0, 0, 71, 239, 255, 255, 192, 0, 0, 17, 135, 135, 143, 244, …]
     1d415717-0c41-b480 50677
```

I would like to know how to copy the code in Python to receive the same output. Unfortunately, I don't know how this condition works

```
if ((i = t [e] ^ n.charCodeAt (o)) === t [e]) {
```

Is there anyone kind enough to write me the code ready or at least explain how to transform it? Thanks so much

My actual Python code:

```
    bit28 = [x for x in bit28][28::]

          e    t       n         r
          |    |       |         |
          V    V       V         V
    print(e, bit28, trackid, unkownValue) 
    temp_i = 0
    temp_o = 0
    for k in range(e, unkownValue):
      if (temp_o > len(trackid) - 1 and (temp_o == 0)):
        print(bit28[k] ^ ord(trackid[temp_o]))
          if((temp_i == bit28[k] ^ ord(trackid[temp_o]) == bit28[k])):
            print("Error decoding sample preview")
            break
          bit28[k] = temp_i
          #print(temp_i)
      temp_o = temp_o + 1
    return k
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the XOR operator, try building your code up from 2 Boolean expressions

See this for more information:
https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_XOR.html